# Using a function to unload multiple queries from Redshift to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have one Redshift table with content like

```
-----------------------
UserId | Data1 | Data2.... 
-----------------------
user1  | data1 | data2....
user1  | data1 | data2....
user2  | data11| data21...
```

I have around 6 million distinct userId.
For each id, I want to unload data to s3 with path having *UserId*, something like

```
unload ('select * from <table_name> where UserId = <user_id>')   
to 's3://mybucket/unload/tableName/<userId>'
```

Problem is I don't want to call 6 million times to Redshift.

Is there anyway I can create tmp table in redshift containing all distinct *UserId*  and iterate over that tmp table and call above unload statements for each UserID in *disticntUserIds*. I am looking for solution which is internal to Redshift itself like UDF/functions, rather than external.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create a temp table in redshift, and this is likely the best option for you. You can create the table then unload that table like this:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_name AS SELECT * FROM orig_table_name WHERE UserId = user_id;
UNLOAD (SELECT * FROM temp_name) TO 'mybucket/unload/tableName/<userId>';
DROP TABLE temp_name;
```

Comment: This is precisely what OP asked for at the conclusion of their question. It is up to them for how to execute this statement. I agree with your comment in that this will need to be handled externally, but I was simply providing a way to "create tmp table in redshift containing distinct UserId and iterate over that tmp table and call above unload statements."

Comment: @ketcham thanks for reply. I am looking for solution for which I need NOT to call Redshift from external source. This will not help me in avoiding same

Answer (score 1):

[Stored Procedures in Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-create.html) permit the use of the `UNLOAD` command.

So, in theory, you could write a stored procedure that loops through a list of values and calls `UNLOAD` for each value.

See: [Supported PL/pgSQL Statements - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_PLpgSQL-statements.html)

Comment: thanks for reply. I will try creating function. I have to check about time taken by redshift function to unload millions of data to s3. If function is executing in single thread, it will take lot of time to do same. After POC, I will revert back to post